# How do I test if a function is called in Meteor.startup using jasmine?

Tags: node.js, meteor, jasmine, meteor-velocity

I have the following code in a file called server.js:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    setupMail();
});
```

I want to create a unit test to make sure `setupMail` is being called in `Meteor.startup`. How do I do that? This is what I have in serverSpec.js:

```
describe("Meteor startup", function(){
    it("should call setupMail", function(){
        spyOn(global, "setupMail").and.callThrough();
        expect(setupMail).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

The test is running, but it's not passing. I think that's because `Meteor.startup` is stubbed. Is there any way I can test to see what was passed inside the callback?

Comment: spyOn does not allow methods within the stubbed method to be called. so anything startup calls is not going to be called.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this link :

http://xolv.io/blog-posts/2013/04/unit-testing-with-meteor

I did like this

Meteor.startup(initServer);

instead of

Meteor.startup(function(){
              initServer
            });

where initServer is only containing Meteor.publish call and did not follow stub part ass given in above link

And in test:

describe('Server startup', function(){

```
'use strict';

it('should publish Notes', function(){
    spyOn(Meteor, 'publish');
    Meteor.startup(initServer);
    expect(Meteor.publish).toHaveBeenCalledWith('notes', findNotes);
});});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When providing external links, please explain what information they contain.